# I have a problem with making a slider for products on my site

Tags: javascript, slider

I have written the code but it says product.length is not defined. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIn5r.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kz9W.jpg)

I have created an array that called Products and includes objects for products and I wanted to make a slider for those products but it didn't work well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to learn [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help) here. You should not post pictures of code and instead post the actual code (as text) in your question.  Having said that, if your array is named `Products`, then you should be accessing `Products.length`, not `product.length`.

Answer (score -3):

You probably have that error because you did not send any value for the parameter product when you call the function slide. You have to send the list in the parenthesis.